# Access Parent Data Context using Code

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

If I want to bind to parent data Context data using XAML , the I could write the following:

```
<UserControl>
<RadGridView x:Name="Parentgrid">

  <RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
               <RadGridView x:Name="childGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Result, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"  
                                     />
  </RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>

</RadGridView>
</UserControl>
```

> But how do I do that using code considering that the code is in a different class , let's say attached propertey . So I am able to access the sender and args like following:

```
 parentGrid.LoadingRowDetails += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        RadGridView gridView = args.DetailsElement.FindName("childGrid") as RadGridView;

                        if (gridView != default(RadGridView))
                        {
                            gridView = //Should be able to access DataContext.Result
                        }


                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for a specific type you can walk the visual tree using a method like FindVisualParent from here: [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls)

At that point you've basically done the equivalent of the RelativeSource part of the binding and can access the DataContext on the returned object.